# How to track a series of key presses in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I'm extremely new to JavaScript and don't know where I'm going wrong. I would like to make a function that executes after a correct series of keyEvents. Essentially, when a user presses keys , "j", "a", "c", "o", and "b" in this order (and this order only) an element on my web Page will become visible. This element is currently hidden using a CSS style tag: `<div id="hideaway" style="display:none;">`

```js
<script> 

 function keyListener(event) {
 event = event || window.event; //capture the event, and ensure we have an event
    var key = event.key || event.which || event.keyCode; //find the key that was pressed
    if(key==106) { //this is for 'j'
     document.getElementById("hideaway").style.display="block";
        event = event || window.event; //capture the event, and ensure we have an event
        var key = event.key || event.which || event.keyCode; //find the key that was pressed
  if(key==97) { //this is for 'a'
         event = event || window.event; //capture the event, and ensure we have an event
         var key = event.key || event.which || event.keyCode; //find the key that was pressed
   if(key==99) { //this is for 'c'
          event = event || window.event; //capture the event, and ensure we have an event
          var key = event.key || event.which || event.keyCode; //find the key that was pressed
    if(key==111) { //this is for 'o'
           event = event || window.event; //capture the event, and ensure we have an event
           var key = event.key || event.which || event.keyCode; //find the key that was pressed
     if(key==98) { //this is for 'b'
            event = event || window.event; //capture the event, and ensure we have an event
            var key = event.key || event.which || event.keyCode; //find the key that was pressed
               document.getElementById('hideaway').style.display='block';
         
        }
       }
      }
        }
    }  
}
  
document.getElementById("hideaway").addEventListener("keydown", keyListener);
</script>
```

All comments are appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I implemented a Konami code easter egg like this:

```
var code = "";
window.addEventListener("keydown",function(e) {
    code = (code+String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode || e.which)).substr(-11);
    if( code == "&&((%'%'BA ") {
        window.removeEventListener("keydown",arguments.callee);
        // do stuff here
    }
},false);
```

The important things here are:

- `.substr(-11)` trims the input sequence to 11 characters - in your case, you'll want `-5`, the length of "jacob"
- Letters are uppercase. You should check for `JACOB`
- In the above, the `code` uses the corresponding characters for the keycode values for the arrow keys. In your case, you just need the letters, so don't worry about those.

Comment: So based on your experience, I believe it should be -6, and not -5. Correct? Btw this works! Thank you.

Comment: @Jacob I made some edits and messed it up a bit, but you got the idea so that's all good :D

Answer (score 2):

one way of doing it:

http://codepen.io/christianpugliese/pen/GpKJXN

```
var PASSCODE = ['j','a','c','o','b'],
    current = 0,
    logger = document.getElementById('logger');

function keyListener(e) {
    var code = e.keyCode || e.which,
      str = String.fromCharCode(code);

    if(str === PASSCODE[current]){
        current++;
        logger.innerHTML += str;
        console.log(current, PASSCODE.length);
        if(current >= PASSCODE.length){
          console.log('voi la');
        }
  } else {
      current = 0;
      logger.innerHTML = '';
  }

}

document.addEventListener("keypress", keyListener);
```

Answer (score 1):

In answer to why it didn't work.

1. Browser javascript is event driven. A keydown listener function will get called at the start of each key press. So each code repetition of

   ```
   event = event || window.event; //capture the event, and ensure we have an event
   var key = event.key || event.which || event.keyCode; //find the key that was pressed
   ```

is not waiting for a new key down event but simply accessing values associated with the current key press multiple times. To fix this the handler has to remember the state of how many characters have been matched in previous events before taking action.

2. Registering a non capturing event listener on a hidden block is unlikely to get executed: the block cannot be the target of an event nor receive events bubbling up from child elements. The solution to this is either to register the listener globally or perhaps use event capture (the 3rd parameter of addEventListener).

A worked example to illustrate these points follows. If unfamiliar with them please read up on object literals and the Function.prototype.bind method. The example also waits for page load before doing anything.

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><title>EasterEgg</title><meta charset="utf-8">
<script>

var easterEgg = 
{ str: "jacob",
  length: 5,
  got: 0,
  blockId: "hideaway",

  test: function(event)
  {  event = event || window.event;
     var c = event.key;
     if(!c) // legacy method
     {  var keyCode = event.keyCode || event.which;
        c = String.fromCharCode(keyCode);
     }
     if( c.toLowerCase() != this.str.charAt(this.got))
        this.got = 0;  // start again
     else
        if(  ++this.got == this.length)
        {   document.getElementById(this.blockId).style.display="block";
            window.removeEventListener("keydown", this.test, false);
        };
     return true;
  },
}
easterEgg.test = easterEgg.test.bind(easterEgg);

window.addEventListener("load", function()
   { window.addEventListener("keydown", easterEgg.test, false);
   }, false);

</script>
</head>
<body><header>Hello</header>
  <div id="hideaway" style="display:none"> SURPRISE! </div>
</body>
</html>
```